# How to send emails to the member of mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I have developed a windows form using vb.net that adds the data into the database. I have used a free mysql host provider db4free.net. The database is for my practice,. The database has the table Roaster which has the columns like ID(autoIncreas), members_name(text), members_email(unique, varchar), members_class(text). Now, i would like to know a way that allows me to send the email to the members of the database. Like extracting the, email address and send all of them the same message. How will I be able to do that? I have no idea, help me out guys.

Comment: This is too broad, we help with specific issues... Please update with what you have tried.

Comment: I searched google for the possible answer. The possible solution that I found was to either to use Php or to use Database mail. And I do not think, Php will be the right option, because it is not a website from where I want to send the email. That is why I wanted to know, the right solution to my problem.

Comment: Php will work, you can call it from a desktop application or the web...